# how to build a docker container which can read data from hive?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, streamlit

I'm trying to build a docker image uses pyhive to connect to hive db which can be accessed on the same machine,

I use official python 3.7.16 as base image, python package installation fails on installing pyhive

`requirements.txt`:

```
pandas==1.3.5
plotly
streamlit
pyecharts
streamlit_echarts
sasl
thrift
thrift-sasl
pyhive
```

```
FROM python:3.7.16
USER root

RUN mkdir -p /home/service/workspace
WORKDIR /home/service/workspace
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

CMD ["streamlit" ,"run" ,"my_streamlit_APP.py"]
```

error as follows

```
Building wheels for collected packages: sasl, thrift, pyhive, pure-sasl, validators, future
  Building wheel for sasl (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for sasl (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
      copying sasl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
      running egg_info
      writing sasl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to sasl.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
      copying sasl/saslwrapper.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
      copying sasl/saslwrapper.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
      running build_ext
      building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Isasl -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/sasl/saslwrapper.o
      In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:629:
      sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:10: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
         22 | #include <sasl/sasl.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sasl
  Running setup.py clean for sasl
  Building wheel for thrift (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for thrift (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for thrift: filename=thrift-0.16.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=460490 sha256=022e85ae21b308e4dcf2bd21847a13c2828c420f3e384ca205b65f9cf75686b1
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/4f/97/c0/67ad0483932737b065d4a84732a5bfdb5c61e30d23d217dd4c
  Building wheel for pyhive (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyhive (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pyhive: filename=PyHive-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl size=51576 sha256=97f01f2815744716861585ba3a11b97bdf223ec9b7c7192cb81e45d6b69515f9
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/ce/ff/b5/fc4b39d9102e5e9431803a1b91199faa252915bcaae55bb7ff
  Building wheel for pure-sasl (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pure-sasl (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pure-sasl: filename=pure_sasl-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl size=11443 sha256=43831e80b8547513256c3f1137d397878d6ed4a92358fca876a88a56c3575544
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f0/f0/01/d54cdfca4826c896c0e27e83aea9e599fd0b91943acffc1504
  Building wheel for validators (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for validators (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for validators: filename=validators-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl size=19581 sha256=c53b096a771e3090f0738d8b94f198eca432679e61b414eecc7508c7a2fb7d23
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/16/2c/b4/bee4ff00f1396725acf6fa020fd9d43f930d22d4f150ee6e56
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.3-py3-none-any.whl size=492035 sha256=606a631dd78fe17423f07f1c64811142346b5a6513aadbda4fd9e3f1745ba038
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c8/ff/15/d835921035fec8b42e31c108329e4b200365ac8573bc5f56d8
Successfully built thrift pyhive pure-sasl validators future
Failed to build sasl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for sasl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm also thinking about pyspark, but will pyspark work if I don't have spark in docker? I just want to read data from hive, so I think I shouldn't build entire spark cluster in image...